# How to add many views to GridLayout without blocking UI?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, grid-layout

I want to display a grid layout in a fragment with thousands (>1.000) grid cells. In order to save code lines, I want to add the grid cells programmatically when the fragment is created. The grid cells do not have to do more than just each of them individually displaying a certain colour.

The problem is, whenever the fragment is created, the UI is blocked for several seconds because the grid layout has to be setup first.
I tried making use of `AsyncLayoutInflater` but that doesn't really solve my problem since the xml layout itself is very small and is inflated without blocking the UI. Creating and adding thousands of views to the grid layout after the xml layout was inflated is what blocks the UI.

So my question is, how can I add all these grid cells to my grid layout in the background without blocking the UI?

My code:

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupGrid()
    }

    private fun setupGrid() {
        // Row and column count is currently set to 60
        for (yPos in 0 until gridLayout.rowCount) {
            for (xPos in 0 until gridLayout.columnCount) {
                val gridCell = ImageView(activity)
                val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(yPos, 1f), GridLayout.spec(xPos, 1f))
                gridCell.layoutParams = params
                gridLayout.addView(gridCell)
            }
        }
    }
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="240dp"
        android:columnCount="60"
        android:rowCount="60"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot how it should look like:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as the Android docs say, one should never call any methods or constructors on any view outside the UI thread since it is not thread safe. It may compile and actually run but it is unsafe to use.

I came up with a solution/workaround which actually only delays the UI block with a higher chance of the user not taking notice of it. This may only work in my specific scenario since I populate my grid with thousands of views only after a network connection was established. Populating the view still blocks the UI but the user may not notice it. A little tweak how to reduce the blocking UI time is described below.

The key to that is making use of an OnLayoutChangedListener. Once I have added all my views to my gridLayout, I call gridLayout.addOnChangeListener and implemented the listener to take care of the grid cells' layout params.

Here's the code:

```
fun configureGridLayout(gridHeight: Int, gridWidth: Int) {
        println("Setting grid dimensions to: ${gridHeight}x${gridWidth}")
        runOnUiThread {
            gridLayout.rowCount = gridHeight
            gridLayout.columnCount = gridWidth
            for (g in 0 until gridHeight * gridWidth) {
                val gridCell = View(context!!)
                gridLayout.addView(gridCell)
            }
            gridLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(LayoutChangeListener(gridLayout, this))
        }
    }



 // This callback is fired when fragment was completely rendered in order to reduce UI blocking time
class LayoutChangeListener(private val gridLayout: GridLayout, private val gridLayoutConfiguredListener: GridLayoutConfiguredListener) : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {

    override fun onLayoutChange(v: View?, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, oldLeft: Int, oldTop: Int, oldRight: Int, oldBottom: Int) {
        v?.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)
        val gridRowCount = gridLayout.rowCount
        val gridColumnCount = gridLayout.columnCount
        val gridHeight = gridLayout.height
        val gridWidth = gridLayout.width
        val margin = 1
        val h = gridHeight / gridRowCount
        val w = gridWidth / gridColumnCount

        for (yPos in 0 until gridRowCount) {
            for (xPos in 0 until gridColumnCount) {
                val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
                params.height = h - 2 * margin
                params.width = w - 2 * margin
                params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)
                // Use post to get rid of "requestView() was called twice" errors
                gridLayout.getChildAt(yPos * gridColumnCount + xPos).post {
                    gridLayout.getChildAt(yPos * gridColumnCount + xPos).layoutParams = params
                }
            }
        }
        gridLayoutConfiguredListener.onGridLayoutConfigured()
    }
}
```